# No creative spec found for given adgroup while creating Facebook ads using FB api

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-marketing-api

I have a facebook campaign, adSet and an adcreative which I have created using the Facebook API. However when I try to create an ad using these three endpoints`(:I think they are called endpoints)` it gives an error `No creative spec found for given adgroup.` Here is my code to create the ad with images,adsets and campaign earlier created:

```
FB.api('act_xxxxxxxx/adcreatives', 'POST', {
name: 'My Testworthy Ad Creative',
title: 'Facebook Marketing Partners',
body: 'Get exactly the things you need from your marketing.',
image_url: 'img url',
object_url: 'https://www.facebookmarketingpartners.com',
access_token:'app access token for selected permissions'

        },function(adcreativeresponse){
          console.log(adcreativeresponse.id);
          FB.api('/act_xxxxxxxx/ads','POST',  {
          creative:["{\"creative_id\" : \"adcreativeresponse.id /*or a static creative_id*/\"}"],
          name:"tryncatch",
          adset_id:"adsetId",
          status:"PAUSED",
          access_token:"app access token with the required permissions selected"},
          function(response) {
                                console.log("response for ad");
                                                 console.log(response);// 
                                                 Insert your code here
                             }
                                            );

                                        } );
```

As shown in the code , I create an `adcreative` which returns the node id of the `adcreative` created, which I use in the `response` function to create an `ad` with all the parameters gathered earlier, but it gives me an error as shown in the image provided after logging `"response for ad"`.
[image]

Is there something that I am missing here.

Comment: I have the same problem but in Python.
I provide `adset_id` & `creative` but getting the same old `No creative spec found for given adgroup`. I will update when I find any answer

Comment: try this `"creative": {"creative_id":<CREATIVE_ID>}` (without the array)

Comment: Hi Jun, I tried without the "[" "]" and then it gave error saying creative is not compatible with the ads. Did it work out for ya ?

Comment: This is exactly what it says now after some changes : " The adgroup's creative is incompatible with the objective of the campaign group the adgroup belongs to."    error_user_title : "Invalid Creative For Objective"

so I need to post an ad_creatives in a different way or create my adsets with some additional parameter

Comment: Yes. the solution for me worked. It seems that you were trying to associate an ad creative with either a campaign / ad-set whose configuration do not normally support the creative of your interest.
Hope you find the working combination :)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the adset id and it worked, seems like those adsets were delete and were pending deletion review. By the way have you tried creating a carousel ad yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for the key `creative` inside your param object should be:

```
"creative": {"creative_id":<CREATIVE_ID>} // without the array
```

as it states in official Facebook documentation for [creating ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup#Creating):

> creative (AdCreative):
>
> This field is required for create. The ID of the ad creative to be used by this ad. You can read more about creatives here. You should supply the ID within an object as follows:
>
> `{"creative_id": <CREATIVE_ID>}`

Comment: Yes it is right, I changed it to just like that but then there was another issue, the adset I had used, was incorrect , I reviewed changes in all the adsets on facebook adverts and created a new adset and used its id, like I mentioned in the comments above . Thanks though :D .  Marking it right so that people know what the issue was, since this has not been addressed much in any of the forums !